# Image processing in Python on google colab

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, google-colaboratory, image-stitching

I want to take two identical photos and using a library to indicate or highlight where the difference is (display the difference). I used the code below but I am getting an error when it seeing an output. Both photos are identical the only difference is one contains cancer cells. So in other words, the code with a highlight cancer cell. [image](like in the photo attached)
But if there is another way I can go it please let me know!

Here is the code:

```py
from PIL import Image ,ImageChops
img1 = Image.open('./download1.jpg')
img2 = Image.open('./download.jpg')

diff = ImageChops.difference = (img1, img2)

if diff.getbbox():
  diff.show()
```

Here is the error output I recieve

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-e547971e9933> in <module>()
      5 diff = ImageChops.difference = (img, img2)
      6 
----> 7 if diff.getbbox():
      8   diff.show()

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'getbbox'
```

Comment: You're doing ```diff = ImageChops.difference = (img1, img2)``` instead of ```diff = ImageChops.difference(img1, img2)```, therefore setting ```diff``` to the tuple ```(img1, img2)```.

Comment: @TheHalf-BloodPrince thank you but now it's saying ----> 5 diff = ImageChops.difference(img1, img2)
      6 
      7 if diff.getbbox():

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing `diff = ImageChops.difference = (img1, img2)` and what you really want to do is `diff = ImageChops.difference(img1, img2)`. Your initial code was just setting `diff` to the tuple `(img1, img2)`, thus the error.

Comment: Thank you i did that but now its saying

Comment: ----> 5 diff = ImageChops.difference(img1, img2)
      6 
      7 if diff.getbbox():

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: Have you tried running your code entirely again (including when you import PIL)?

Comment: Half-Bood Prince yes I have

Comment: here's the link to my google colab code if you wanna see https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Wm2iK6BHicIqGj6JiV2hEpIy61DI16Ha?usp=sharing

Comment: It's weird because it runs smoothly on my side and I'm not getting the TypeError you're having...

Comment: aw really? are you even able to see the difference like the example I have above too?

Comment: @quix234: you have assigned to the function, so it no longer is a function. You must restart your Python interpreter to fix it.